# How to add an InputBox to search for words within all files in a designated folder

Tags: vba, ms-word, inputbox

I use the macro below, created by Macropod, to run through all files in a designated folder to search for desired words.

How could the search terms be entered via an InputBox rather than manually adjusting the VBA code?

```vb
Sub CollateDocumentData()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, strDocNm As String, strTmp As String, strOut As String
    Dim wdDoc As Document, i As Long: Const StrFnd As String = "than,and"
    strDocNm = ActiveDocument.FullName
    strFolder = GetFolder: If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
    strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc", vbNormal)
    While strFile <> ""
      If strFolder & "\" & strFile <> strDocNm Then
        Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
        strTmp = ""
        With wdDoc
          With .range.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            For i = 0 To UBound(Split(StrFnd, ","))
              .Text = Split(StrFnd, ",")(i)
              .Execute
              If .Found = True Then strTmp = strTmp & vbCr & "" & Split(StrFnd, ",")(i)
            Next
          End With
          If strTmp <> "" Then strOut = strOut & vbCr & strFile & ": " & strTmp & Chr(13)
          .Close SaveChanges:=True
        End With
      End If
      strFile = Dir()
    Wend
    Set wdDoc = Nothing

    'If you want the results to be given in a new temporary document, remove the 'MsgBox' line below
    'If you want the results to be given in a message box within the current document, remove the 'Document.Add' and 'ActiveDocument' lines below
    'Documents.Add
    'ActiveDocument.range.Text = "The following matches were made:" & strOut
    MsgBox ("The following matches were made:" & vbCr & strOut)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub

    Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim oFolder As Object
    GetFolder = ""
    Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
    If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.path
    Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `"\*.doc"` So you only want `.doc` file nor `.docx` or `.docm`?
2. 

> to search for words

> to search for desired words.

However `.Replacement.Text = ""` so you want to clear the words not search only? And in your code, there is no parameter Replace used to `.Execute`, how does it work properly?

3. If you do not want to clear the words, then you shouldn't set the parameter `.Replacement.Text = ""`, and I'll do this first in my code below.
4. If you do not clear the words and have no marks to do, why do you need `.Close SaveChanges:=True`? There is no modification at all in that document while running the code.

Conclude the above so I'd like to rewrite your code like this:

```vb
Sub CollateDocumentData()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, strDocNm As String, strTmp As String, strOut As String
    'Dim wdDoc As Document, i As Long: Const StrFnd As String = "than,and"
    
    Dim wdDoc As Document, i As Long
    Static StrFnd As String, StrFndArr As Variant, UBStrFndArr As Integer
    
    StrFnd = VBA.Trim(VBA.InputBox("Plz input the words you want to find! " & vbCr & vbCr _
                            & "Please separate each word with a comma and no spaces!", "Input the words to find", StrFnd))
    If StrFnd = "" Then Exit Sub
    StrFndArr = Split(StrFnd, ",")
    UBStrFndArr = UBound(StrFndArr)
    
    strDocNm = ActiveDocument.FullName
    'strFolder = GetFolder: If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
    strFolder = GetFolder(): If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
    strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc", vbNormal)
    
    While strFile <> ""
      'If strFolder & "\" & strFile <> strDocNm Then
      If VBA.StrComp(strFolder & "\" & strFile, strDocNm) <> 0 Then
        Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
        strTmp = ""
        With wdDoc
          With .Range.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            '.Replacement.ClearFormatting
            '.Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            For i = 0 To UBStrFndArr 'UBound(Split(StrFnd, ","))
              .Text = StrFndArr(i) 'Split(StrFnd, ",")(i)
              .Execute 'Replace:=wdReplaceAll
              If .Found = True Then strTmp = strTmp & vbCr & "" & StrFndArr(i) 'Split(StrFnd, ",")(i)
            Next
          End With
          If strTmp <> "" Then strOut = strOut & vbCr & strFile & ": " & strTmp & Chr(13)
'          If Not .Saved Then
'            .Close SaveChanges:=True
'          Else
            .Close
'          End If
        End With
      End If
      strFile = Dir()
    Wend
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    
    'If you want the results to be given in a new temporary document, remove the 'MsgBox' line below
    'If you want the results to be given in a message box within the current document, remove the 'Document.Add' and 'ActiveDocument' lines below
    'Documents.Add
    'ActiveDocument.range.Text = "The following matches were made:" & strOut
    MsgBox ("The following matches were made:" & vbCr & strOut)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim oFolder As Object
    GetFolder = ""
    Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
    If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
    Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

Is this what you want?

If you just want to find and return the search result then using `VBA.InStr` function and `Content.Text` will be more efficient.

```vb
Sub CollateDocumentData_InstrContent()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, strDocNm As String, strTmp As String, strOut As String
    'Dim wdDoc As Document, i As Long: Const StrFnd As String = "than,and"
    
    Dim wdDoc As Document, i As Long
    Static StrFnd As String, StrFndArr As Variant, UBStrFndArr As Integer
    
    StrFnd = VBA.Trim(VBA.InputBox("Plz input the words you want to find! " & vbCr & vbCr _
                            & "Please separate each word with a comma and no spaces!", "Input the words to find", StrFnd))
    If StrFnd = "" Then Exit Sub
    StrFndArr = Split(StrFnd, ",")
    UBStrFndArr = UBound(StrFndArr)
    
    strDocNm = ActiveDocument.FullName
    'strFolder = GetFolder: If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
    strFolder = GetFolder(): If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
    strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc", vbNormal)
    
    While strFile <> ""
      'If strFolder & "\" & strFile <> strDocNm Then
      If VBA.StrComp(strFolder & "\" & strFile, strDocNm) <> 0 Then
        Set wdDoc = VBA.GetObject(strFolder & "\" & strFile)
        strTmp = ""
        With wdDoc
            For i = 0 To UBStrFndArr
              If VBA.InStr(1, .Content.Text, StrFndArr(i), vbTextCompare) Then
                strTmp = strTmp & vbCr & "" & StrFndArr(i)
              End If
            Next
            If strTmp <> "" Then strOut = strOut & vbCr & strFile & ": " & strTmp & Chr(13)
          
            .Close

        End With
      End If
      strFile = Dir()
    Wend
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    
    'If you want the results to be given in a new temporary document, remove the 'MsgBox' line below
    'If you want the results to be given in a message box within the current document, remove the 'Document.Add' and 'ActiveDocument' lines below
    'Documents.Add
    'ActiveDocument.range.Text = "The following matches were made:" & strOut
    MsgBox ("The following matches were made:" & vbCr & strOut)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Oscar, that's amazing thank you! Works perfectly. You're right - I only need to search and not replace. Regarding the file extension, I only need to check .doc and .docx files. Thanks again!

Comment: @Luke so would you like to accept this answer and close your question?